# asp.net variables in aspx page

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm clearly missing something fundamental here but could someone explain why label 2 isn't populated?

My codebehind

```
public partial class namespace : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    public string TestString = "test";

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        lbl1.Text = TestString;
    }

}
```

my aspx text labels:

```
<asp:Label ID="lbl1" runat="server" /><br/>
<asp:Label ID="lbl2" runat="server" Text='<%# TestString %>' /><br />
```

Comment: You are missing the Page.DataBind(); in code-behind. Check the topic that Stijn mentioned

Comment: http://weblogs.asp.net/infinitiesloop/archive/2006/08/09/The-CodeExpressionBuilder.aspx is useful, thanks

Answer (score 3):

`<%# %>` is used for binding in `data controls` like this : `<%# Eval("id") %>`, you are trying to write a property on `code front`.

try this:

```
<asp:Label ID="lbl2" runat="server"><%= TestString %></asp:Label>
```